# Regex Java String Split by Asterisk

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Help is needed.

```
line.split("*");
```

I used this line of code to split a string into an asterisk mark. However, I got an error from my compiler. It says, "INVALID REGULAR EXPRESSION: DANGLING META CHARACTER '*'"

How to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`*` has special meaning in regular expressions.  You have to escape it.

```
line.split("\\*");
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because you used a "*", that is a regular expression. If you want to use this caracter, you need tu put something like that:

```
line.split("\\*");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this statement:

```
line.split("\\*");
```

Answer (score 2):

***** is a meta character in regular expression. It is used for matching 0 or more elements. If you want to use ***** as a normal character and not as a special character (i.e. skip its behavior as a meta character) then add escape characters before it.

Eg: `String[] split = line.split("\\*");`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the following [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), `*` has a special meaning, ***zero or more times***.

| Greedy | Reluctant | Possessive | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X? | X?? | X?+ | X, once or not at all |
| X* | X*? | X*+ | X, zero or more times |
| X+ | X+? | X++ | X, one or more times |
| X{n} | X{n}? | X{n}+ | X, exactly n times |
| X{n,} | X{n,}? | X{n,}+ | X, at least n times |
| X{n,m} | X{n,m}? | X{n,m}+ | X, at least n but not more than m times |

Therefore, you need to escape it with a `\`. However, `\` too is a special character and therefore you need to put an additional `\` to escape `\`. Thus, the required pattern becomes `\\*`.

```
String[] arr = line.split("\\*");
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Alternatively, as [suggested by anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492353/regex-java-string-split-by-asterisk/75085298?noredirect=1#comment132537607_75085298), you can use `[*]`. The character, `*` is not required to be escaped when used as a [character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html).

```
String[] arr = line.split("[*]");
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava for the valuable suggestion. I have incorporated your suggestion in my answer now.