# Arterisk can not be split from String

Tags: java, split

I'm practicing Java with a fraction calculator. All it does is, the calculator will determine what operation is given in the input (e.g. `1/4 + 2/4`) to calculate the fractions and return the result. However it seems the program fails to split arterisk `*` from the `String [] fractionsplit` and gives me following error message:

```
String multiplication() {
        String fractioninput = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
        System.out.println("You entered " + fractioninput);
        String [] fractionsplit = fractioninput.split("//*/");  

        Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(fractionsplit[0]);
        Integer den1 = Integer.parseInt(fractionsplit[1]);
        Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(fractionsplit[2]);
        Integer den2 = Integer.parseInt(fractionsplit[3]);

        result = ((num1 * num2) + "/" + (den1 * den2));
        System.out.println("This is multiplication of fraction. Result is " + result);
        return result;
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2*3"
>           at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
>           at Encapsulation.MultiplicationDivision.multiplication(fractiontest1.java:77)
>           at Encapsulation.fractiontest1.main(fractiontest1.java:19)

I'm using the same way to develop methods for addition, subtraction and division operations, they are all working just as expected, only `multiplication()` specifically fails. I referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492353/regex-java-string-split-by-single-asterisk) but still having the issue. I appreciate if anyone could point out the issue to me. Thanks

Comment: What should this part do? `fractioninput.split("//*/")` The referred question uses `\\*` instead of `//*`

Comment: I believe the accepted answer on the question you linked to is the answer you are looking for.  In your line with `fractioninput.split("//*/")`, you need to use `fractioninput.split("\\*")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `*` is a meta-character, you need to escape it with a `\`. And since `\` also is a meta-character, you need another `\` to escape this. Thus, you need to use `\\*` as the regex.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exp = "4*5";
        String[] arr = exp.split("\\*");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 5]
```